# Ranking a higher tier dataframe first, and then ranking a lower tier dataframe second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have two dataframes:

```
            x            y
 df1<-     1.0          5.31  
           0.9          4.22
           0.1          4.57


            x            y
 df2<-     1.3          4.71    
           0.3          4.54
```

df1 can be viewed as being a higher tier than df2 (i.e. the "God tier" dataframe, or "first class"). I want to rank the x column values of df1 first, which is easy enough using the code below.

Input:

```
df1['rank'] = df1['x'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
            x            y          rank
 df1<-     1.0          5.31          1
           0.9          4.22          2
           0.1          4.57          3
```

However, it is the next part that I am having some difficulty figuring out how to do...

I then want to rank the x column of df2 (i.e. the "lower tier" dataframe, or "second class"), continuing on from the rank values of df1 to give an output of:

```
            x            y          rank
 df2<-     1.3          4.71          4
           0.3          4.54          5
```

(i.e. the largest x value of df2 will be ranked as being below the lowest x value of df1 - even if the x values of df2 are larger than in df1).

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest is add max value of `rank` in `df1`:

```
df2['rank'] = df2['x'].rank(ascending=False) + df1['rank'].max()
print (df2)
     x     y  rank
0  1.3  4.71   4.0
1  0.3  4.54   5.0
```